# Where do I find my Facebook Audience ID?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to get the audience ID from the audiences I created in Power Editor but I can find no way to retrieve the Audience ID. I've read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/custom-audience-targeting/ but still it does not explain where to get these Audience IDs from.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm assuming your app has access to the Ads API; if not, you can't retrieve the Audience IDs via the API, but the IDs probably aren't useful unless you're creating ads via the API anyway

To retrieve audiences you've created in an account via power editor or the API, you can make an API call to  `https://graph.facebook.com/act_<ACCOUNT ID>/customaudiences` which returns the audiences in the account

You'll need a user access token for an admin of the ad account, whcih has the `ads_management` extended permission

Comment: This looks like what I need, I just have to learn to make API calls now.

Comment: I got a command not found when I tried running an api call through curl.

Comment: That sounds like a problem with curl, the API would have responded with an error if your machine could reach it

Comment: You can also get it from the URL if you go into the advertiser dashboard and click on tools-> audiences then click on your audience you need an ID for. If you look at the URL in your location bar find ids=99999999 -- that's your ID. (I crossed checked this ID from what I get from an API call as suggested here.)

Comment: It is showing "(#2635) You are calling a deprecated version of the Ads API. Please update to the latest version: v2.10.", now

Comment: This answer predates the version being mandatory for the Ads API- add the version number in the call path - `graph.facebook.com/v2.10/...`

Comment: Thanks you very much, I dont know why this is not very clear in the Facebook Docs

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to get the audience IDs via web interface. Here are the steps:

- select an ad set with the audience you need
- press Export & Import button

[image: see attachment 1]

- choose Selected

Facebook will generate a .csv file. In this file, you'll find all ad set's parameters, including Included Custom Audiences and Excluded Custom Audiences with IDs.

[image: see attachment 2]

Answer (score -2):

Once you have a list of all the target audience profile URLs, you can get their Facebook ID numbers by going to www.findmyfacebookid.com

Or you can also find anybody’s ID by adding the word “graph” to their profile URL, like this http://graph.facebook.com/awesomename

Comment: Have you tried Facebook's Graph API explorer? Heres a link to an already existing discussion about it:
http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/11925/get-facebook-ids-of-all-contacts

Comment: This answer doesn't address what the OP was asking about